# Luggage lockers in downtown Hanoi?

Tags: luggage-storage, train-stations, hanoi

I'm going to be visiting Hanoi for one day and taking an overnight train. Is there a place in downtown Hanoi where I can lock my luggage for the day? Alternatively, does the Hanoi train station have a luggage locker/bag check?

Answer (score 4):

**There seems to be luggage lockers at the Hanoi train station.** The web has some traces on the topic, including [this Tripadvisor thread, which quotes directions and costs (updated in 2013)](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g293924-i8595-k5752652-Luggage_lockers_at_Hanoi_airport_or_train_station-Hanoi.html):

> Hi, there are luggage lockers available at Hanoi train station. I used them today -12 hours for about $2.
>
> They are located at the far end of the booking office and fit my large pack easily. They lock with a key but there is space to put a padlock as well (which I did).

[This Virtual Tourist review has a picture of the storage lockers](http://www.virtualtourist.com/travel/Asia/Vietnam/Thu_Do_Ha_Noi/Hanoi-1481679/Transportation-Hanoi-Trains-BR-1.html):

> With some time to kill before our departure we FOUND and USED luggage LOCKERS that were found on the extreme left hand side of the facility. To get to them you must pass by the ticket purchasing area and keep on going to the end of the building. It’s not a large facility at all so you should have no issues finding these lockers.
>
> [image: Luggage Lockers at Hanoi train station] 
> <sup>*Luggage Lockers, Greggor58, fair use*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

**Updated 2019**, there is already automatic luggage storage locker at Hanoi train station. The locker has 18 doors with 12 extra-large doors with size ~ 95x50x50cm which can take upto 02 backpacks of 90 liters size (5500 cubic inches) while the rest 06 large doors can fit upto 02 backpacks/suitcases of 65 liters size. It's self-service with touch-screen and the price is at VND50,000 per 04 hours for a single door (which can contain multiple items with sizes described above). You pay for the duration used in 04-hour blocks, so there is no limitation on the usage time.

**IMPORTANT: Be aware of SCAMMERS** - Please do NOT use the service **offered by the local railway staffs** approaching you, which they will put all your luggage to a room with much more expensive costs (they charge PER ITEM, not PER DOOR which can contain multiple items like the automatic locker supports). That means if you have 04 backpacks/suitcases they will charge you 4 times, while you can put all those into 02 doors maximum with at least 50% less of cost, and also there is no standard cost for this manual service, **you'll be charged randomly** (in a more expensive way)

The automatic locker can be easily found at the right side if you enter the Main Hall of the station, with the blue color and yellow sign. It looks like below:
[image: locker at hanoi train station]
[image]

And we're using it:
[image]

Hope this helps.